# Can a Static method access a private method of the same class?

Tags: c++, static-methods

I have this question because of the singleton/named constructor. In both cases, the real constructors are protected or private, neither of which can be accessed from outside.

For example, a short named constructor is this:

```
 class A
{
  public:
    static A createA() { return A(0); } // named constructor
  private:
    A (int x);
};
int main(void)
{
   A a = A::createA(); 
}
```

I thought static method can only access static data member, or access private data/method via an existing object.
However, in the above code, private constructor `A()` isn't static, and at the time it is being called, no object exists either.
So the only explanation I can think of is that static method can access non-static private method of the same class. Can anyone please either affirm or negate my thought, possibly with some lines of explanations?

I apologize if this is too trivial however the key words are too common and I wasn't able to find an answer in dozens of google pages. Thanks in advance.

Comment: DR; TL; Yes it can.

Comment: I assume you made a typo, and meant "So the only explanation I can think of is that static method can access *non-static private* method of the same class" instead of "... *static* ..."

Comment: Thanks! Do you have some reference that I can look at?

Comment: @SanderDeDycker yes, you're right. I'll correct now.

Comment: why do you put an answer in the question section? If you want to answer your own question you can do this, but please put it as an answer not as addition to the question

Comment: @tobi303 I came across several times that op summed up a short answer. So I thought it is something I should do. Did I misunderstand it? If so, let me know, I'll delete the summation part. Thanks.

Comment: @FlowingCloud imho only in rare cases this is appropriate (eg. when there are many diverging answers and a summary of them can help the reader), but in general users expect the question in the question and answers in the answers. One strong argument against it is up/down votes. If you put the answer in the question there is no way to up/downvote your summary

Comment: @tobi303 Sure. I'll delete them. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 29):

A static member function has the same access rights as a non static member function.  So yes, it can access any public, protected, and private variable in the class.  However you need to pass an instance of the class to the function for the function to be able to access the member.  Otherwise a static function can only directly access any other static member in the class.

Comment: That's what I am confused. At the time I am calling the constructor, the object doesn't even exist. So can a static function access the private constructor when no instance exists at all?

Comment: @FlowingCloud See below: "The static function can access private members, but other than that it is just like any function defined outside of the class." For running the constructor, you don't need an object. For every other non-static class method, you do.

Comment: Simply put, it's the rules. My boss likes to say that a class is always a `friend` of itself.

Comment: @FlowingCloud A constructor is like a static function.  It does not need an instance because it is creating a instance, this is why it is called a special member function.  So calling it is okay as you do not need an instance.

Answer (score 14):

According to the standard *§11/p2 Member access control [class.access] **(Emphasis Mine)***:

> **A member of a class can also access all the names to which the class
>   has access.** A local class of a member function may access the same
>   names that the member function itself may access.<sup>113</sup>
>
> <sub>113) Access permissions are thus transitive and cumulative to nested and local classes</sub>.

Since a static member function is a member of a class it has access to all the names to which the class has access and consequently to the constructor of the class itself.

Consequently, in your example:

```
class A {
  A(int x);  
public:
  static A createA() { return A(0); } // named constructor  
};
```

static member function `A::createA()` has access to call `private` constructor `A::A(int)`.

Answer (score 4):

Within a function of a class (including `static` functions), *all* the `private` member data and functions are accessible, even if you are dealing with a different *instance* of that class within that function.

You often exploit this when writing *copy constructors* and *assignment operators*.

(My boss often talks about how he would like to be able to disable this behaviour using some kind of `friend = delete;` syntax.)

Comment: I don't think static method can access a private Data member without first having an object, am I right? I am more interested in whether static method can access a private Method(constructor)? //I saw your explanation above. Thank you!

Comment: No you'd always need an object to refer to a non-static data member. But a static function can call a private function; in your case the *constructor*.

Comment: Sorry, just a little clarification. Can a static function call ANY private function, or just constructor (without referring to an object)?

Comment: A static function can only call static functions or constructors.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can. The static function can access private members, but other than that it is just like any function defined outside of the class. Especially, since it doesn't have a `this` pointer (ie. is not "bound" to any specific instance), you won't be able to access any members directly (which are always "bound" to an instance): if you wanted to do that, you need a an instance from somewhere:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A
{
  public:
    static A createA() { return A(0); }
    static void dosomething(A *a) { return a->something(); }
  private:
    A (int x) { cout << "ctor" << endl; }
    void something() { cout << "something" << endl; }
};

int main(void)
{
   A a = A::createA(); 
   A::dosomething(&a); 
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: that's exactly the question: when static method is called to create an object, no object exists yet. So how is it able to access the private constructor?

Answer (score 2):

Followup on this, why is this not allowed then ? If it is allowed to create an object, why isn't it allowed to create a pointer to it ?

```
using namespace std;
class A
{
  public:
    static std::unique_ptr<A> createA() {
    return std::make_unique<A>(0);
    }
  private:
    A (int x) { y = x;}
    int y;
};
int main(void)
{
   auto a = A::createA(); 
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Perhaps this should be asked as a new question. It will get more attention in that case.

Comment: It's because your constructor is private so it cannot be instantiated from the `std::make_unique()` library call. It would be fine if your constructor was public.

Comment: In this case, return std::unique_ptr<A>(new int(0)); would be allowed. I'm curious if anyone knows a way around having to use "new" in this case, which is apparently frowned upon in modern C++.

Answer (score 0):

Your static method is not accessing any static member nor any non-static member of an existing instance.
It's just creating a new instance.

Comment: It does. But a constructor is not an instance-method. The fact the constructor is private, is irrelevant: A member (static or none) has access to anything defined within that class.