# C++ Singleton private constructor not accessible from static function

Tags: c++, singleton

I have a singleton class declaration here:

```
#ifndef GLFW_CONTEXT_H
#define GLFW_CONTEXT_H

#include <memory>

class GLFWContextSingleton
{
public:
    static std::shared_ptr<GLFWContextSingleton> GetInstance();
    ~GLFWContextSingleton();
    GLFWContextSingleton(const GLFWContextSingleton& other) = delete;
    GLFWContextSingleton* operator=(const GLFWContextSingleton* other) = delete;
    
private:
    GLFWContextSingleton();
};

#endif
```

and an implementation of the `GetInstance` function shown here

```
std::shared_ptr<GLFWContextSingleton> GLFWContextSingleton::GetInstance()
{
    static std::weak_ptr<GLFWContextSingleton> weak_singleton_instance;
    auto singleton_instance = weak_singleton_instance.lock();

    if (singleton_instance == nullptr)
    {
        singleton_instance = std::make_shared<GLFWContextSingleton>();
        weak_singleton_instance = singleton_instance;
    }

    return singleton_instance;
}
```

However the call to `std::make_shared<GLFWContextSingleton>()` gives me an error saying

```
‘GLFWContextSingleton::GLFWContextSingleton()’ is private within this context
```

I thought that this static method would have access to the private member functions. What is causing this and how do I fix it?

Comment: The function `std::make_shared<GLFWContextSingleton>()` is not a `friend` of your class. It can't use the `private` constructor.

Comment: @TedLyngmo doesn't a static function automatically have access to all private, public, and protected variables and functions of that class? Maybe I did not understand this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39144979/can-a-static-method-access-a-private-method-of-the-same-class.

Comment: Yes, the `static` function has access. You can do `singleton_instance.reset(new GLFWContextSingleton);` - it's the function you call, `make_shared`, that doesn't have access.

Comment: Any reason why you want a `shared_ptr` to the singleton btw? Wouldn't a Mayers-kind-of-singleton work?

Comment: @TedLyngmo I thought it might be better to use a `shared_ptr` because I can use a `weak_ptr` to test if the object has been initialized or not. But now that you mention it, I don't see a need for it and probably can just return a reference to a bare static object itself.

Comment: Yes, unless there's some special reason to use a `shared_ptr`, that's what I'd do - if I made a singleton at all :-)

Comment: Not to mention, the way `GetInstance()` is shown, there is a race condition if multiple threads were to call `GetInstance()` at the same time. Returning a static object would avoid that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The static function does have access to private members. `make_shared` does not.

`make_shared` is a template function that forwards the arguments it gets and calls the constructor of the specified class. So the call to the default constructor happens inside the `make_shared` function, not inside the `GetInstance` function, hence the error.

One way to deal with this is to use a private nested class as the only argument to the constructor.

```
#include <memory>

class GLFWContextSingleton
{
private:
    struct PrivateTag {};
public:
    static std::shared_ptr<GLFWContextSingleton> GetInstance();
    ~GLFWContextSingleton();
    GLFWContextSingleton(const GLFWContextSingleton& other) = delete;
    GLFWContextSingleton* operator=(const GLFWContextSingleton* other) = delete;
    
    GLFWContextSingleton(PrivateTag);
};

std::shared_ptr<GLFWContextSingleton> GLFWContextSingleton::GetInstance()
{
    static std::weak_ptr<GLFWContextSingleton> weak_singleton_instance;
    auto singleton_instance = weak_singleton_instance.lock();

    if (singleton_instance == nullptr)
    {
        singleton_instance = std::make_shared<GLFWContextSingleton>(PrivateTag{});
        weak_singleton_instance = singleton_instance;
    }

    return singleton_instance;
}

int main() {

}
```

This way we keep the constructor public, but in order to use it we need a `PrivateTag`, only accessible to members of the class.

Comment: Thanks! I completely forgot that access permissions for the class were only available at the immediate level of the static function and not propagated down to other calls.